# How do you open a file from Atom in python? (osX)

Tags: python, bash, macos

Im really really new to programming & basically i write the code in a text editor called atom, i save it & call it like 'text.py' and then i open terminal and write 'python3 text.py' and this shows up:

/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python: can't open file 'test.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

& when i drag/drop the file... this shows up:
-bash: /Users/nadiahussain/Documents/Programming/Test.py: Permission denied

Anyone know what to do? Pls

Comment: Try to `cd /Users/nadiahussain/Documents/Programming` then run `python3 Test.py`. Test.py must be in your CWD which I believe it's not right now.

Comment: In your terminal, try `python3 /Users/nadiahussain/Documents/Programming/Test.py`.

Comment: You guys just saved my life no joke, thank you!!! So wait everytime i open i file .. i have to do this? is there a quick way? .... Also abccd what do you mean CWD? what is that?

Comment: Current working directory, and I made a mistake....the file can also be in your PATH

Comment: Oh okay, so how do i take it out of CWD? where should it be?

Comment: You mean you want it to be in your PATH. Which you can accomplish by typing this in the terminal: `PATH=$PATH:/Users/nadiahussain/Documents/Programming`

Comment: This way you wouldn't have to type the full path everytime

Comment: Okay i typed that in, closed terminal and reopened terminal & now i just wrote 'python3 test.py' and  im back in the same position again.. its saying the No file directory.. Ugh :( this is so hard...

Comment: The PATH modification that abccd showed you is only temporary: it only affects that terminal session and disappears when you close the terminal. You _could_  modify the `export PATH` line in your `/Users/nadiahussain/.bashrc`, which gets run every time you start a terminal. Or just follow abccd's first suggestion and do `cd /Users/nadiahussain/Documents/Programming` when you want to do some Python work. The terminal remembers the current directory until you close it, so you don't need to re-type that `cd` command every time you run a Python script.

Comment: Okay so ill just follow abccd's first suggestion then.. y'all are awesome, Thank youuuuu(: